# (Oracle + dapper C#) Выполнить функцию oracle c входными параметрами которая возвращает type as object

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper

У меня возникли трудности с выполнением функции oracle c входными параметрами которая возвращает type as object с сопровождением ошибки System.ArgumentException: "Invalid parameter binding".

```
function fn_logon(v_user_login varchar2, v_password varchar2)
return tp_user
```

где tp_user это

```
    create or replace type tp_user as object
(  
  id number,
  user_login varchar2(30),
  first_name varchar2(30),
  name varchar2(30),
  last_name varchar2(30),
  id_role number,
  is_active number
)
```

вызов c `

```
public static void LogOn(AutorizationRequest req)
        {
            DynamicParameters dynamicParametrs = new DynamicParameters();
            dynamicParametrs.Add(":v_user_login", req.UserName);
            dynamicParametrs.Add(":v_password", req.Password);
            dynamicParametrs.Add(":v_result", dbType: DbType.Object, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            
            using (IDbConnection con = config.OracleConfig.GetConnection())
                {
                var results = con.Query<AutorizationResponse>("PKG_AUTORIZATION.FN_LOGON", dynamicParametrs, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);               
                config.OracleConfig.CloseConnection(con);
                }            
        }
    public class AutorizationResponse
    {      

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int IdRole { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure fn_logon(v_user_login varchar2, v_password varchar2)
return tp_user
```

Процедура не может возвращать никакое значение кроме своих out-параметров.
Это должна быть функция.

Comment: Согласен. Спасибо за внимательность, это я переделывал функцию в процедуру и пытался вернуть object как out  параметр. Одно мгновение и исправлено.

Comment: Но это лишь была ошибка в публикации вопроса который я исправил. По прежнему я не могу найти решение.

Comment: вместо `dbType: DbType.Object` нужно указать более конкретный тип возвращаемого значения, т.к. оракл требует точного указания всех типов.  не знаю, умеет ли c# указать юзер-тип в DynamicParameters.  но можно вернуть не объект, а курсор, это с# точно умеет.